# User's PowerShell History Save Path Location on Linux and macOS?

Tags: linux, macos, powershell, history

Where is the PowerShell history save file located on non-Windows OSs?

Answer (score 5):

Following the [XDG Base Directory specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-0.6.html) the history save file is located at:

`~/.local/share/powershell/PSReadline/ConsoleHost_history.txt`

Source: [What's New in PowerShell Core 6.0 - Filesystem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-powershell-core-60?view=powershell-6#filesystem)